# Reseller API seem to be underdeveloped?

Tags: google-reseller-api

I'm trying to use Googles reseller API to better control and operate our business.

The API can only list seats for Google-Apps-For-Business with an ANNUAL plan. This results in misleading statistics since a big part are FLEXIBLE.
There are no way to see which Google-Drive-storage has Assigned Licenses or how many.

Are there any way around this? - or any ideas behind it?

Have the API not been fully developed? - if so, when will it be?

*Love to know.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some days ago, Google has finaly added the feature that was lacking!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the planName and skuId properties on the subscription resource:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reseller/v1/reference/subscriptions#resource

That should get you Flex plan data, and also data related to Google Drive storage.